# How to filter combo extjs when there is empty value?

Tags: extjs4

> Value in combo box doesn't filter and value "null" still show.

This code SkpdCombo.js and I didn't find what error. So please help me what's mistake and what should I do with this code?

```
Ext.define('App.view.skpd.SkpdCombo', {
    extend: 'App.view.CommonCombo',
    alias: 'widget.SkpdCombo',
    fieldLabel: 'Skpd',
    displayField:'_combo_',
    valueField: 'skpd_id',
    queryMode: 'remote',
    initComponent: function() {
        if (!this.store){
            this.store = new App.store.SkpdStore();
            this.store.load();
        }

        this.callParent();

        this.store.on('load', function(store, records, successful, operation, eOpts){
            var value_no = this.getValue();

            if (store.find('skpd_no', value_no) != null){
                this.setValue(value_no);
            }else{
                this.store.clearFilter(true);
            }
        }, this);
    }
});
```

Ok I'll wait for your answer guys. Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle replicating this problem?

Comment: If you want to remove specific records from the store you may specify appropriated filter config in your store, i.e. filters: [function(item) {return item.skpd_no !== null;}]

Answer (score 0):

`this.store.load();` is called before the store `onLoad` event is defined.

Also
 `this.callParent();`
I think must be the first call in the constructor.